# Newton's Law case: feather and astronaut?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, work

How do I solve for the final velocity of both astronaut and feather, after the astronaut extends their legs against the feather?

I understand there is an equal and opposite reaction, but am confused conceptualizing it.  For instance, an object with more mass than the feather, would cause greater velocity for astronaut and less for the feather.

I recall reading somewhere that this is solved with a system of equations.

Comment: what do you mean "after the astronaught extends their legs against the feather?"

Comment: @jensenpaull If at the starting position the astronaut has their legs pulled together and feet touching the feather.  The astronaut then using muscles extends their feet.  I'm not sure how placing the feet a further distance would change the result as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You know that the momentum of the system is conserved.  So momentum of the feather must be opposite the momentum of the astronaut.  Therefore the magnitude of the velocities (speeds) must be in inverse proportion to the masses of the objects (assuming we are analyzing in the frame where the center of mass is at rest).

$$p_{\text{net}} = 0$$
$$p_{\text{a}} = -p_{\text{b}}$$
$$m_{\text{a}}v_{\text{a}} = -m_{\text{b}}v_{\text{b}}$$
$$\left\lvert\frac{{v_{\text{a}}}} {v_{\text{b}}}\right\rvert = \frac{m_{\text{b}}} {m_{\text{a}}}$$

Likewise, energy goes as the square of the velocity, so you can find the energy distribution from the mass distribution.  If you know the total work done during the separation, you know the total energy that can be distributed to the two objects.